# Inject EntityFrameworkCore DbContext in AzureFunction

Tags: dependency-injection, azure-functions

I have Solution like

ABC.Domain (.net standard 2.0)

ABC.Service (.net standard 2.0 + EFCore + EFCoreSQL)

ABC.AzureFunction (.net standard 2.0) v2

ABC.Web (.net core 2.0)

I'm using UnitOfWork and Repository pattern in my ABC.Service and inject using .net core native DI extension. it is working in web project but I'm not able to resolve DbContext reference in Azure Functions.

ABC.Web (it' working)

Startup.cs

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
.AddDbContext<AnimalHubContext>(o =>
{
o.UseSqlServer(this.Configuration["Data:ConnectionString"]);
});
services.AddScoped<IAccountRepository, AccountRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        services.AddSingleton<IAppConfigurationManager, AppConfigurationManager>();
        services.AddSingleton<ICachingService, CachingService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddScoped<ABCContext>();
```

ABC.AzureFunction

[AzureFunction DI](https://blog.wille-zone.de/post/azure-functions-dependency-injection/)

```
public static async Task RunAsync([QueueTrigger("analyzeimage",
        Connection = "animalhubnonblob_STORAGE")]string myQueueItem,
        TraceWriter log,
        [Inject(typeof(IUnitOfWork))]IUnitOfWork uow)
```

InjectConfiguration.cs

```
private void RegisterServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        string connectionString = "****************";
        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<AnimalHubContext>((serviceProvider, options)>
                 options.UseSqlServer(connectionString)
                .UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider));

        services.AddScoped<ABCContext>();
        services.AddScoped<IAccountRepository, AccountRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<ICategoryRepository, CategoryRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
    }
```

Error
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing functio
n: AnalyzeImageFunction. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'uow'. 
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection: Cannot resolve scoped service 'AnimalHub.Persistence.IUnitOfWork' from root provider.

Comment: Quote from AzureFunction DI article *`This solution only supports transient and singleton scoped services.`*

Comment: There was a followup article on how to allow scoped services https://blog.wille-zone.de/post/azure-functions-proper-dependency-injection/

Comment: @Nkosi Singleton and Scoped working very well for me, I'm only facing issue with DbContext. I also tried with a singleton. no luck

Comment: @PankajRawat do you really need DI ? My argument is that DI is not so relevant with serverless app

Comment: @Thomas To write better unit test we need DI, I'm using service in both function & web.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: Don't remember exact what I did but, there was some issue with my DI. first I inject non-dependent classes then add other class.

Comment: Also I updated all nuget to latest version, currently using Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.0.8